# Minimum set of vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

(Not an assignment)

Motivation: You can imagine a street of houses, and we consider two houses to be neighbors if the distance between them is no more than 10 houses. We want a minimal set of representatives so that at least each house is represented by itself or one of its neighbors. I have therefore represented each house by a vertex and all sets of neighbors are represented by cliques (a house or a vertex can belong to several cliques).

Problem formulation:

There is given undirected graph $G$ of $n$ vertices.

I'm looking for $A=\{v_0,...,v_k\}$ which represents the minimal set of vertices where : each clique $c$ in $G$ with size $k$ have at least one vertex $v_i$ in commun with $A$.

Or :

find the minimal set
$A$
of vertices, if we remove these vertices there will be no clique of size $k$
in

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What's the motivation behind this problem? Any attempts that you have done?

Comment: Motivation: You can imagine a street of houses, and we consider two houses to be neighbors if the distance between them is no more than 10 houses. We want a minimal set of representatives so that at least each house is represented by itself or one of its neighbors. I have therefore represented each house by a vertex and all sets of neighbors are represented by cliques (a house or a vertex can belong to several cliques).
Tested: the solution is not a vertex cover nor a maximum/or minimum independent set (I have counterexamples).

Comment: I can reformulate the problem to find the minimal set $A$ of vertices, if we remove these vertices there will be no clique of size $k$ in $G$

Comment: You can edit your question to include the motivation and your thoughts, which should improve your question. As for your specific example in the motivation, it seems to me that vertex cover is the answer; do I overlook something?

Comment: I edited the question, thanks!
For vertex cover, the solution will give the set of vertices that cover all edges. This set is way bigger than the minimal set $A$ am looking for, I don't need to cover all edges. The optimal is just a set $A$ that makes sure that each vertex in $G$ is directly connected to a vertex $v$ in $A$. I hope you get my point

Comment: Right, that was my mistake. I think [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) is the correct solution for your specific example instead.

Comment: Oh thanks, that looks like it. Only need to add the constraint that the dominating set is minimal, which I think makes the problem harder. Can you write your comment as an answer please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can imagine a street of houses, and we consider two houses to be neighbors if the distance between them is no more than 10 houses. We want a minimal set of representatives so that at least each house is represented by itself or one of its neighbors.

This problem is equivalent to finding a minimum [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set), if we represent the street of houses as a graph where each house is a vertex and each two neighbouring houses are represented as an edge between the two corresponding vertices.

This problem in general is NP-complete, but the specific problem above is easily solvable; simply choose the $11$th house, $32$rd house, $53$th house, $74$th house, etc. to ensure that every house is within a $10$-house distance from the selected houses.

Comment: Thanks, yes the solution is easy in the scenario i presented.